# Edit rendering parameter data from a rendering toolbar

Tags: sitecore-client, presentation

I would like to update some data on my rendering parameter template from the rendering toolbar. Like when I click a custom experience button, I could set my vertical alignment field, on the rendering's parameter template.

I understand that the rendering data is stored in xml in the rendering field. And that the parameter data is url encoded in the xml. Just not sure how to update it from a button.

When I try and update it from a customer experience button, the parameters object is readonly in the command arguments.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Chris do you mean you want to expose these in the toolbar like rendering variants in SXA? If so I was thinking supporting this kind of thing in standard Sitecore would be cool too but I'm not sure how possible it would be to implement an actual interface for editing rendering paramaters within the Chrome toolbar.

I've only really found solutions that provide custom experience buttons. However this post from non linearcreations goes a bit further than this and might prove useful:

http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2016/05/How-to-customize-the-Sitecore-Experience-Editor.aspx

If anyone knows how to expose textboxes or dropdowns in the chrome toolbar though I'd be really interested in knowing how.

Comment: Does rendering variants update rendering parameters when you select them? If so, yes this would be great to bring to Sitecore. I need to stand up a fresh install of SXA again.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works under the hood as I've only seen it in action. But perhaps if you standup an instance of SXA and dig into the code further then this would give you an idea of how to do this. I'm assuming they just have some js that adds the dropdown for the variants into the tool bar.

Comment: I'll dig into it also. Would be a great extension.